# Keyboard Shortcut Conflict While Playing Minecraft

Tags: shortcut-keys, minecraft

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with Java Runtime Environment 8. When I hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to sprint in Minecraft, and (while holding ctrl) try to use <kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>7</kbd> to switch between hotbar slots, nothing happens. As soon as I release <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, however, the keys work again. This does not happen on Windows or MAC **using the same keyboard and computer**.

Does Ubuntu have a key shortcut that is causing this?

Comment: it might be an issue of Ubuntu platform. Did you try to report it to [Minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/) ?

Comment: @Mirza Did so, Mojang responded saying it wasn't an issue with Minecraft.